# How to generates JWT token to access the microservices via API getaway

Tags: authentication, jwt, microservices, api-gateway

I am trying to build Project with microservices architecture in .net core.
Say I have created the below services

-Service 1

-Service 2

Then I used the API-Gateway and added the routes for Service1 and Servic2. And at last, enable the JWT Authorization layer.

Now I'm confused about how to generate tokens along with the custom claims for the users based on username and password so that this token will be validated at API-Gateway and served services accordingly?

Should I create another Service (say IdentityService) where the user can generate the token based on username and password?

-If yes then, Where to place that service in the API Gateway or Outside the API Gateway?

What is the best way?

Thank you,
Saurabh Khandelwal.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are so many approaches available, However, each scenario has pros and cons.

As an example, I always use Abp Framework's approach for any project that I believe is going to live for a long period of time with a lot of changes down the road.
By using this approach you can concentrate your IdentityServer inside the Domain layer as per below:

[image: Domain Layer]

Then use a method to generate any settings for tokens. For example:

```
    var client = await _clientRepository.FindByClientIdAsync(name);
    if (client == null)
    {
        client = await _clientRepository.InsertAsync(
            new Client(
                _guidGenerator.Create(),
                name
            )
            {
                ClientName = name,
                ProtocolType = "oidc",
                Description = name,
                AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 31536000, //365 days
                    AccessTokenLifetime = 31536000, //365 days
                    AuthorizationCodeLifetime = 300,
                IdentityTokenLifetime = 300,
                RequireConsent = false,
                FrontChannelLogoutUri = frontChannelLogoutUri,
                RequireClientSecret = requireClientSecret,
                RequirePkce = requirePkce
            },
            autoSave: true
        );
    }
```

This approach is super great for DDD patterns I believe. you can check it out here [Domain Driven Design using ABP](https://github.com/abpframework/abp)